# Why am I getting "The OAuth client was deleted" errors?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I'm working with the Gmail API for my first time, and I've been getting "The OAuth client was deleted" errors (longer version below). I don't know why this would be. To be sure, I redid the whole OAuth process and generated a new credentials file with the same name as the old one, but nothing changed.

Here's a longer version of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\User\localcopy.py", line 62, in <module>
    creds.refresh(Request())
  File "C:\User\myenv\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\credentials.py", 
line 345, in refresh
    ) = reauth.refresh_grant(
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\User\myenv\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\reauth.py", line 
367, in refresh_grant
    _client._handle_error_response(response_data, retryable_error)
  File "C:\User\myenv\Lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\_client.py", line 
74, in _handle_error_response
    raise exceptions.RefreshError(
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('deleted_client: The OAuth client was deleted.', 
{'error': 'deleted_client', 'error_description': 'The OAuth client was deleted.'})
```

EDIT: Here are the parts of the code that seem potentially relevant. (The credentials.json file is for accessing the Google Sheets API via a service account, and credentials2.json is my attempt at going the OAuth route with the Gmail API in addition to that.)

```
credentials_file = "C:\\User\\credentials.json"
scopes = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send' ]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(credentials_file, scopes)
client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json')
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials2.json', ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'])
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
try:
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Failed to build service: {e}')
    service = None
```

Comment: please edit your question and includ eyour code.